Using @Autowired inside EntityListener
i'm developing a websocket, and i created an entity listener that after un update on a table must alert the websocket.
In doing so, i need a value that i should retrieve from the db, but since in entity listeners methods i should not do query, in this project we already implemented a cache system, where the value i need is actually stored.
So, i'm autowiring in the entity listener this CacheService class, but i always get the NullPointerException. Also, i need to autowire the Handler of the WebSocket, i need to use it to send the message to every session.
I already read all the topics here, but none could help me.
I tried annotating the EntityListener class with @Component, but nothing. Also, i made the class extend SpringBeanAutowiringSupport, but also didn't work.
@Component
public class EListener extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {

    @Autowired
    private LockHandler handler;
    @Autowired
    private CacheService cacheService;

    @PostUpdate
    private void afterUpdate(Elab elab){

        final DSTate state1 = cacheService.getAllStates().stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getId().equals(elab.getFkState())).findFirst().orElse(new DState());
        handler.sendMessage(state1);


I did a lot of researches about this, but the last questions are from 3-4 years ago, so maybe now there's a better way of implementing this.

Why not just do this from the service instead of trying to shoehorn this into an entity listener? Autowiring is possible but how depends on the version of Spring (Spring Boot as well?) and Hibernate that are in use.

that's how my PM asked me to implement this. I'm on Spring Boot 3.2.0, Java 17, last version of Hibernate

Why on earth is your PM dictating how you implement something. But that might be me. Don't make your method private as that will lead to weird issues. How did you register the entity listener? Autowiring should work, which makes me thing you are messing around with manual configuration disabling auto-config and thus disabling proper integration.

I registered the entity by using the tag '@EntityListeners(EListener.class)' on top of the entity that i update. I have touched nothing else, that's why i find it so strange

I'm not saying that you have touched anything, but if you are configuring the EntityManagerFactory yourself somewhere int he configuration or by other means integration will be disabled.

As suggested in the comments, you are using a JPA-based approach to inject the EventListener around the entity, but a Spring-based approach for the bean injection, and this does not work (see spring autowiring not working from a non-spring managed class).
You can try to do some kind of "bridge" between the two worlds, as suggested in the comments of the above issue: use a class that has statically the method to get the application context, that can be called by the listener to obtain the references to the needed beans.

This has been resolved since the introduction of the Hibernate BeanContainer which will be used to create and autowire needed beans. Spring provided one that integrates with this to make autowiring work. Spring Boot automatically configures this as well as when you are using a LocalSessionFactoryBean. So basically what is mentioned there is no longer correct/relevant.

@M.Deinum I wasn't aware of the BeanContainer solution, thanks!
